# Wrong screenorientation

Tags: screen, hdmi, tv, dvi

I have a problem with my second screen. I want to use my TV to watch videos on it. So I took a DVI-I to HDMI cable, sticked the DVI end into my computer and the HDMI end to my TV.   The screen shown up, but was in the wrong orientation. The sidebar was on the ground and the whole screen was turned. Ubuntu thinks that the TV is higher than it is wide. Have anyone the answer on this?

Thanks, SydoxX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try ARandR, for configuring dual monitors. Or look for the orientation parameter in "Display" in the Settings manager. Hope i was helpfull.